# Storing filter coefficients in python

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, scipy, filtering, signal-processing

I have one pythonfile which fetches live data from an ECG device, and sends that to a website. The samplingfrequency of the ECG device is 200 Hz, and the python code fetches this data every second. I want to filter this data, so for every batch (of 1 second) I call  another python file which contains my filters. Every filter have some coefficients that it finds from for example `scipy.signal.butter(order, norm_cut, btype='low', analog=False, output='ba')`, but the coefficients will always stay the same. So my questions is, is there a way to just store these cooeficents as global variable across the files? So its doesnt calculate these every second it gets called.

The code structure is something like this:
Main.py

```
from filters import ecgfilter
while True:
    raw = fetch_data()
    cleaned = ecgfilter(raw, fs=200)
    send2web(cleaned)
```

filters.py

```
def butterLowpass(cutoff:float, fs:float, order=5)->np.ndarray:
    norm_cut = cutoff/(0.5*fs)
    b, a = signal.butter(order, norm_cut, btype='low', analog=False, output='ba')
    return b, a

def lowpassFilter(data, cutoff:float, fs:float, order=5):
    b, a = butterLowpass(cutoff, fs, order)
    filtered = signal.lfilter(b,a,data)
    return filtered

def butterHighpass(cutoff:float, fs:float, order=5)->np.ndarray:
    
    norm_cut = cutoff/(0.5*fs)
    b, a = signal.butter(order, norm_cut, btype='high', analog=False, output='ba')
    return b, a

def highpassFilter(data, cutoff:float, fs:float, order=5):
    b, a = butterHighpass(cutoff, fs, order)
    filtered = signal.lfilter(b,a,data)
    return filtered
def notchFilter(cutoff:float, fs:float, Q:float):
    norm_cut = cutoff/(0.5*fs)
    b, a = signal.iirnotch(norm_cut, Q)
    return b, a

def notch(data, powerline_freq:float, fs:float, Q:float):
    b, a = notchFilter(powerline_freq, fs, Q)
    signal = signal.lfilter(b,a,data)
    return signal

def ecgfilter(raw, Fs=200.0):
    data = raw
    high_filt = highpassFilter(signal, cutoff=0.5, fs=Fs)
    loHi = lowpassFilter(high_filt, cutoff=40.0, fs=Fs)
    filtered = notch(loHi,50.0, Fs, 25)
    return filtered
```

As you see these b, a coefficients I want to store, an minimize the calls for. Thought of storing them in a file, but still will aslo result in a lot of calls.

Note: Ofc I could have taken bigger batches of data, but the point is to live stream this data to a website, so then it wouldnt look continous.

Comment: spelling: `python`, `coefficient`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the filter coefficients in file-level global variables (example below).

I suggest using SOS-form instead of ba-form; SOS-form has better numerical properties.

If you're processing data in 1s chunks, but you're not *dropping* any data, look into the initial condition input and (corresponding "final condition" output) to [lfilter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html) and [sosfilt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.sosfilt.html)

Example of code storing coefficients:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal


FSAMPLE = 200 # Hz
LOW_CUT = 40 # Hz
LOW_ORDER = 5
_LOWSOS = signal.butter(LOW_ORDER,
                        LOW_CUT/(0.5*FSAMPLE),
                        output='sos')


def lowpassfilter(raw, Fs=200.0):
    return signal.sosfilt(_LOWSOS, raw)
```

Comment: Thank you, I will test this. So when importing this file in the main file should I then import the entire file so that the global variable are set or will this happen anyways if i just import the functions?
Thank you for the remarks regarding the filter function. I see that there is not much diference as long as the filter order is low. Do you know if there are any speed differences between lfilter and sosfilt?

Comment: You can just import the function or functions you use; each module creates its own namespace, where global variables, etc., live. `sosfilt` is slower, though I don't know how much; you can search the scipy issues list for discussions about this.

Comment: Tested it now, and setting the coefficients as global variables made it run 100 times faster (just some basic testing). Tried the sosfilt, then I got this error: ```ValueError: sos[:, 3] should be all ones```

Comment: Make sure you have `output='sos'` in the call to `butter`.  You can't use SOS for `iirnotch`: it already returns a second order filter, but as numerator and denominator (you could use `signal.tf2sos` to turn those into a SOS).

Comment: Thank you! the reason the sosfilt didnt work was a typo by me. But lfilter seams to be a lot faster. From my testing each batch of cleaning took around 1-2 ms with sosfilt, but around 0.04 ms with lfilter